# Как получить имя ос в локальной сети

Tags: python

Мне нужно получит имя ос по ip адресу в локальной сети. Как такое можно выполнить?

Comment: Скорее всего никак

Comment: А как тогда локальные сканеры типа Nmap работают?

Comment: Попробуйте: https://github.com/gil9red/ordering_lunch_at_Nashe_Vse/blob/b7374633cffccae40731700b0d03de75f2468081/api.py#L192

Comment: @videx по косвенным признакам, которые не дают гарантий правильности результата. Ну и если Nmap вас устраивает, то просто запустите его из питона да и всё?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае никак, но можно попробовать сканер. В том числе есть nmap для python: https://pypi.org/project/python-nmap/